# Pandas pct_change() using time series and preserving ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to calculate the perc change occurring between two dates of the values for each id in my df:

```
date        id  a  b
2021-01-01  1   6  4
2021-01-01  2   10 10
2021-01-02  1   3  2
2021-01-02  2   20 20
```

What I'd like to have as a result is:

```
id  ratio_a  ratio_b
1   -0.5     -0.5
2   1.0      1.0
```

I tried playing with [`pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) but I cannot understand how to use it for this.

The data for testing can be generated with this code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.to_datetime(
    [
        datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 2),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 2)
    ]
)

d = {
    'id': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'a': [6, 10, 3, 20],
    'b': [4, 10, 2, 20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=dti)
```

I tried with `df.groupby(by=['id']).pct_change()` and it gives me:

```
            a   b
2021-01-01  NaN NaN
2021-01-01  NaN NaN
2021-01-02  -0.5    -0.5
2021-01-02  1.0 1.0
```

, which is not exactly what I want. I would need a) that dates were sort of aggregated, and b) my ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem `pct_change` not aggregate values, so output has same number of rows like original. First values of each groups are mising values, another values are counts. For preserve `id` is possible use:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id', append=True).groupby('id').pct_change()
print (df1)
                 a    b
           id          
2021-01-01 1   NaN  NaN
           2   NaN  NaN
2021-01-02 1  -0.5 -0.5
           2   1.0  1.0
```

If need remove `NaN`s and first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('id', append=True)
         .groupby('id')
         .pct_change()
         .dropna(how='all')
         .droplevel(level=0))
print (df2)
      a    b
id          
1  -0.5 -0.5
2   1.0  1.0
```

Another alternative solution:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('id', append=True)
         .groupby('id')
         .pct_change()
         .dropna(how='all')
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry to have changed a bit the final result in my question (I realized pct_change did not multiply by 100, so if you wish you can remove `.mul(100)` from your great answer).

Comment: Just to add that `df2.droplevel(level=0)` returns the exact result I wanted. Again, thank you, really appreciate your time and help!